# Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") in method

Tags: java, mysql

I have an issue with the  `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`;

I'd like to create separate class for SQL maintenance and GUI to it. When I input  `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` file in directly in main everything works. When I try to create separate class for SQL maitenance it is throwing bunch of exceptions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = null;

    SqlMaitanance DB1 = new SqlMaitanance();
    DB1.createDB("XD");
}


//Class for SQL maitanance

public class SqlMaitanance extends Example {

//Variables

public static String dataBaseName = "DBFROMMETHOD";
public static String dbTableName;


public static ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
public static ResultSet rs = null;
public static Statement stmt = null;
public static Connection conn = null;
public static final String JdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
public static final String UserName = "root";
public static final String Password = "Herflik$00121";

public static final String Url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + dataBaseName;

//Constructor

public SqlMaitanance() {


    createDB(this.dataBaseName);


}

//Methods

public static void createDB(String dataBaseName){

    String crtTable = "CREATE DATABASE " + dataBaseName;
    try{


        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Url,UserName,Password);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(crtTable);
        rs.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
    //Handle exceptions for ClassforName

    e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally{

        try{
            if(stmt!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
        }// do nothing
        try{
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }


}
```

Error thrown:

> Thu Dec 14 22:35:47 CET 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without
>   server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL
>   5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance
>   with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
>   property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL
>   by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for
>   server certificate verification.
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   database 'dbfrommethod'   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:776)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   SqlMaitanance.createDB(SqlMaitanance.java:40)     at
>   SqlMaitanance.(SqlMaitanance.java:27)   at
>   Example.main(Example.java:24)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: Also check the name of your database.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. I did lot of mistakes. I went through my code and correct it. Here is working answer

```
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.State;
import java.sql.*;

public class SqlMaitanance {

//Variables

public static String dataBaseName;
public static String dbTableName;


public static ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
public static ResultSet rs = null;
public static Statement stmt = null;
public static Connection conn = null;
public static final String JdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
public static final String UserName = "root";
public static final String Password = "Herflik$00121";

public static String Url;

//Constructor
```

Constructor was left empty without reference to the dataBaseName variable

```
public SqlMaitanance() {


}

//Methods
```

Method should have local variable

```
public static void createDB(String dbN){
```

I cannot connect to DB which is not existing hence I have shoren URL

```
    Url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    String crtTable = "CREATE DATABASE " + dbN;

    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Url,UserName,Password);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(crtTable);
        rs.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
    //Handle exceptions for ClassforName

    e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

        e.getException();
    }
    finally{

        try{
            if(stmt!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
        }// do nothing
        try{
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }


}

public static void createTable(){


}



}
```

Sorry for formatting errors.